# How to create feed which mixes records from different other records and is limited to a number using swift 3.0 and CloudKit?

Tags: swift, database, xcode, cloudkit

So I've been working on an app which basically works almost like facebook (far less complex), but is more for schools. It contains Feed, Classes with posts, Groups with posts, friends with posts and more. What I want is to be able to get the posts from friends, groups, and classes I'm in and load them into tableView in News Feed. 
The structure of the database:

```
Post {
   (...)
   user: Reference
   likes: Reference list //users
   comments: Reference list //comments
}

User {
   (...)
   name: String
   surname: String
   friends: Reference list
   posts: Reference list
}

Class {
   (...)
   posts: Reference list 
}
```

My (relevant) code for NewsFeed so far:

```
// Class used for controlling CloudKit
class DatabaseController {  
        var publicDatabase = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase

    func reload() {
        publicDatabase = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
    }

    func networkCheck() -> Bool {
        var networkConnection = true
        doesRecordExist(withRecordName: "test", withFieldName: "test", equalTo: "test") { _, _, error in
            switch CKError(_nsError: error!) {
            case CKError.networkFailure, CKError.networkUnavailable, CKError.serviceUnavailable: networkConnection = false
            default: break
            }
        }
        return networkConnection
    }

    //Q U E R I E S

        func doesRecordExist(withRecordName: String, withFieldName: String, equalTo: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool?, CKRecord?, NSError?) -> Void) {
        print(withFieldName,equalTo)
        //this function checks if a record with specified value of a specified field exists.


        //initiating the query
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "\(withFieldName) == %@", equalTo)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: withRecordName, predicate: predicate)
        publicDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) {results, error in
            if error != nil {
                //if there is an error
                completionHandler(nil, nil, error as NSError?)
                return
            }
            guard let results = results else {
                //if reults are nil
                completionHandler(nil, nil, error as NSError?)
                print("error 2")
                return
            }

            if results.count == 1 {
                //if found
                completionHandler(true, results[0], nil)
                print(results)
            } else {
                //if not found
                completionHandler(false, nil, nil)
                print("not found")
            }
        }
    }

    func getAllRecords(withRecordType: String, withDesiredKeys: [String], sortForkey: String, ascending: Bool, withResultLimit: Int, operations:Int, completionHandler: @escaping ([CKRecord], NSError?) -> Void) {

        //prepare the variables to create a query for wanted records and retrieve them.
        var records: [CKRecord] = []
        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: sortForkey, ascending: ascending)

        let query = CKQuery(recordType: withRecordType, predicate: predicate)
        query.sortDescriptors = [sort]

        //limiting the query using operation
        let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
        operation.desiredKeys = withDesiredKeys
        operation.resultsLimit = withResultLimit

        //completing the query
        operation.recordFetchedBlock = { record in
            records.append(record)
            print(1)
        }

        //executing the operation
        operation.queryCompletionBlock = { [unowned self] (cursor, error) in
            var count = 0

            //checking weather there is a need for more than one operations
            if error != nil && count < operations {
                count += 1
                let newOperation = CKQueryOperation(cursor: cursor!)
                newOperation.queryCompletionBlock = operation.queryCompletionBlock
                self.publicDatabase.add(newOperation)
            } else {
                print(2)
                completionHandler(records, nil)
            }

        }

        publicDatabase.add(operation)
    }
}
```

And

```
class MyFeedTViewController: UITableViewController {
        var posts: [CKRecord]! = []
        var database = DatabaseController()
        var timer: Timer!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60.0, target: self, selector: #selector(MyFeedTViewController.refresh), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timer.fire()

        database.getAllRecords(withRecordType: "Post", withDesiredKeys: ["user","text", "comments", "plusses"], sortForkey: "creationDate", ascending: false, withResultLimit: 5, operations: 1) { records, error in

            if error == nil {
                self.posts = records
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func refresh() {

        database.getAllRecords(withRecordType: "Post", withDesiredKeys: ["user","text", "comments", "plusses"], sortForkey: "creationDate", ascending: false, withResultLimit: 5, operations: 1) { records, error in

            if error == nil {
                if records != self.posts {
                self.posts = records
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(posts.count)
        return posts.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Text Post", for: indexPath) as! PostCell


        // Configure the cell...

        let post = posts[indexPath.row]

        cell.commentsNLabel.setTitle(String((post["comments"] as? Array<Any>)?.count ?? 0) + " comments", for: .normal)

        var name: String!
        var surname: String!

        guard let recordReference: CKReference = (post["user"] as? CKReference) else {
            print("error")
            return cell
        }

        database.publicDatabase.fetch(withRecordID: recordReference.recordID ) { record, error in
            if error == nil {
                name = record!.value(forKey: "name") as? String ?? "null"
                surname = record!.value(forKey: "surname") as? String ?? "null"

                cell.usernameLabel.text = name + " " + surname
                countOperations += 1
            }
        }

        cell.whenPostedLabel.text = EdAppKit().returnStringTillNow(from: (post["creationDate"] as? NSDate) ?? NSDate())

        cell.plusesNLabel.text = String((post["plusses"] as? Array<Any>)?.count ?? 0) + " plusses"

        cell.postText.text = String((post["text"] as? String) ?? "null")

        return cell
    }
}
```

Everything works except retrieving the name and surname of the user and the code isn't yet the code I want for the goal I described at the beginning?
Do any of you have any suggestion on how to do it and how to fix the problem with name and surname? I will really appreciate it!

**EDIT** 
I've fixed the problem with surname and name not showing by fetching the record with specified ID rather than using RecordID only, but I have a next problem, the cells when loading aren't loading items inside of it synchronously but in a messy matter, if somebody knows how to fix it It would be great!